# Pass Value of Input Automatically With Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I was working on passing a value that is put into a text input box, to another text input box as the user types. 
I got everything to work on jsfiddle but for some reason I can't get it to work if I use it anywhere else. Im using pure javascript, not jquery.

So, here is my html code

```
    <input id="imput1" type="text" class="firstbox">
    <p>Box to Retrieve The Input</p>
    <br />

    <input id="gift_card_recipient" type="text" class="replica" value="box1" />
    <input type="text" class="replica2" value="box2" />
```

And the Javascript that I am using to pass the value as the user types, from the first box, to the second box:

```
(function() {
var var1   = document.getElementById('imput1'),
    var2   = document.getElementById('gift_card_recipient'),
    callback = function () {
        var2.value = this.value;
    };

if (var1.addEventListener) {
    var1.addEventListener('keyup', callback);
} else {
    var1.attachEvent('onkeyup', callback);
}
}());
```

Again, I got this to work on jsfiddle, and here is a demo of what it looks like, but for some reason, if I use it on my pc on a html file, or on my server, it wont work. 
I am linking the js file in the header, and also inspected it in chrome. here is the error I got from chrome:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
```

Not really sure why its throwing that. but here is my jsfiddle that I have that actually works. but doesn't on the server or my pc: http://jsfiddle.net/C3SPM/

Comment: where are you adding that javascript code..? try adding it just before <body> closing tag if not already..!

Comment: I have the javascript in a file by itself, and am linking it in through the header.

Answer (score 0):

Include your script block at the end of the body (or after the elements in question). Or wrap your code in an onload/onDomReady handler.

The specific error you are getting is because your code is running before the elements in question have been parsed, which means that `document.getElementById('imput1')` returns `null` because it can't find the element. The reason it works in a fiddle is that by default jsfiddle wraps any JS in an onload handler, so then when the code runs the elements *have* been parsed (you can change this setting in jsfiddle using the drop-down on the left under "Frameworks & Extensions").

Comment: so, if I were to put this in the footer of my website or page, would it execute correctly then?

Comment: That would depend on where your footer is defined. It's reasonably standard to include `<script>` elements either as the last thing before the closing `</body>` tag, in which case you normally don't need to worry about an onload/onDomReady handler, or within the `<head>`, in which case you usually do need an onload/onDomReady handler. Try one of those options and see (just before `</body>` is the simplest change) - if it still doesn't work there might be some other problem.